# Please stop laughing!

Tags: riddle

> Stop laughing, I do not jest.
>   For the time of kings is long gone.
>   Although on paper I still exist, I can assure you that I don't.
>   Flying beasts do not scare me, it's the man under their sigil that defeats me.

HINT

> They keep laughing because they think that I jest... Why would they think that I jest?

Comment: does 'on paper I still exist' refer to a written work of fiction, perhaps?

Comment: @wildBillMunson I am afraid not. Sorry. It has a slightly more literal meaning.

Comment: So it's 'on paper' in a purely literal sense?

Comment: @wildBillMunson I suppose  you could say that.

Comment: Well okay I took a stab in the dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK this is a bit of a 'stab in the dark', but, is it:

> The Joker

Stop laughing, I do not jest.

> In the *Batman* series, the Joker has a comical appearance (which people think is funny) but he is actually a sadistic criminal mastermind. No kidding.

For the time of kings is long gone.

> In the high court of kings, the jester (also known as the joker) was employed to provide entertainment, and serve as 'the fool' for comic relief. We don't need jesters today, as our political leaders provide their own folly.

Although on paper I still exist, I can assure you that I don't.

> The Joker is a playing card, and therefore exists on paper. But it is not included in a standard deck, and is not used by most card games. So it usually doesn't exist.

Flying beasts do not scare me, it's the man under their sigil that defeats me.

> The 'flying beasts' are bats, and the man under their sigil is Batman. The Joker is defeated by Batman each and every time.

Comment: That is the correct answer. The solution to the last hint is perfect. The third one is acceptable, the other two are quite different.

Comment: The first 2 hints are strongly connected to my choice of words in my first hint.

Comment: Does each hint refer to a different meaning of "the joker", i.e. the first two clues don't refer to either the character from Batman or the playing card?? Am I to find two other contexts where "the joker" has meaning?

Comment: Only the last hint refer to the one from batman. The first 2 hints refer to the same meaning of joker.

Comment: So the first three hints all refer to the same meaning, or are the first two different than the third?

Comment: the 4th one refer to the joker in **batman**, the 3rd one refer to the joker on the **playing card**, the first 2 clues refer to **???**

Comment: .... court jesters, presumably?

Comment: Anyone else noticed the phenomenon where you get attached to your original answer and it becomes difficult to let go and explore other possibilities?? :)

Comment: I changed #2. Is that any closer?

Comment: Good enough. Good job

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> [**Tyrion Lannister**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrion_Lannister) 
>  [image]

Stop laughing, I do not jest.

> Due to his little size probably. And off-course an amazing sense of humor which sound funny most of the times.

For the time of kings is long gone.

> He thinks it's the time of the Dragon Queen to hold the Throne - [Daenerys Targaryen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daenerys_Targaryen)

Although on paper I still exist, I can assure you that I don't.

> He may be still an heir to lannister's but he won't be given any place there due to the fact that he betrayed them

Flying beasts do not scare me, it's the man under their sigil that defeats me.

> He is not scared of the dragons but scared by the House Bolton may be(man under their sigil signifies [House Bolton](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Bolton)) 
> [image]

Source- Wikipedia.

Comment: +1 quite interesting, but that is not the correct answer. (the title and the first clue gives pretty big hints.)